# Using 'passwd' then trying ssh

Tags: ssh, unix

An exceptionally newbie question, sorry. I'm running a Debian machine as root:

```
$whoami
root
```

If I carefully change the password (over VNC), it seems to work:

```
debian:/# passwd
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
```

If I then try to ssh in, carefully typing in the password I just set, I get 'Permission denied':

```
:~ ap257$ ssh root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

What could be going wrong?

----UPDATE--------

Solved, see my answer below (I can't accept it until tomorrow). Your thoughts on why on earth this worked would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Most likely the 'root' account is not permitted to log in via SSH.

Locate the config file, usually stored at

```
  /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Look for the line that says

```
 PermitRootLogin No
```

Change it to say

```
PermitRootLogin Yes
```

Make sure you restart the SSH daemon after making the change!

```
service sshd restart
```

Comment: dont enable root to ssh, make other users and give them sudo permissions

Comment: Or only permit key authentication

Comment: If you are security-conscious, yes best practice is to give a regular user sudo capabilities by adding the user to the '/etc/sudoers' file.

Comment: Hm. I don't have this file and 'find' doesn't produce anything by that name either. Do I need to install ssh?

Comment: OK, done apt-get install ssh: opened sshd_config and edited: restarted ssh (using /etc/init.d/ssh restart). Still no joy, still getting 'Permission denied'. :(

Comment: @AP257 - Yes you will need to install the openssh-server package if it is not installed already. I'm not terribly familiar with Debian but I would guess that the SSH client (ssh) is installed by default but the SSH server (sshd) is not. Also, consider what JamesRyan said. I would not recommend allowing root logins over SSH.

Comment: If you did not get an error when issuing the SSH command than OpenSSH is at least installed. If not, you would get a message saying the command 'ssh' is not recognized. Check /var/log/auth.log and /var/log/secure and /var/log/messages for any insightful errors that may help you narrow it down.

Lastly, check /etc/passwd and look for root's line. Make sure there is a shell set for that user, most likely '/bin/bash'. If it is '/bin/false' or something similar, change it. Again restart SSHd.

Remember, root over ssh is a security warning.

Comment: sudo isn't installed by default on Debian, only on Ubuntu. If it's not pre-configured it's a pain to set up. How about logging into the machine as a regular user and using 'su'?

Answer (score 4):

**Create a new user** with `useradd`, then **set the passwd** with `passwd [user].` i.e.

```
useradd johndoe
passwd johndoe
```

Then **SSH using johndoe**, and then use the **switch user** command `su -` to get to root.

---

Note the dash. This is very important to set your environment like you probably want. *Without the dash I believe you would end up at a prompt under root, but would have to use absolute paths. Normally the syntax is su [user], but the default is root if it is omitted.*

Ideally you would also use Sudo, but the above is more proper than simply SSHing in under root. It is likely as mentioned in the other answers your sshd configuration disallows root login.

The reason root login is **disallowed** is **because** remote root access can be **higher risk** than needed security wise. Using the above method you would have to crack two layers to get root access, as opposed to just "knocking down the front door."

**You can also look in /var/log/secure to see why your password was rejected.**

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But that doesn't help - still get 'Permission denied', even logging as my new user....

Comment: What does your /var/log/secure log say? (At the bottom) Or does this file not exist either? Try "tail /var/log/secure"

Comment: No such file. It's a brand new Debian install, maybe that's why?

Comment: hmmm, it should (provided usual vanilla SSH) have been created when you first tried to login, especially if you are getting permission denied. Edit: I looked it up and debian actually doesn't use a logger by default - doh me. It's a long shot, but does lastb show your login attempts on the server your trying to login to? (last would show your successful attempts)

Comment: I'm guessing most people here aren't using the straight debian flavor, alot of the advice is assuming defaults on some flavors. You can also try adding "authpriv.*              /var/log/secure" to your /etc/syslog.conf this may cause the /var/log/secure log to be used for logging the attempts then you could see why the failure is occurring.

Comment: By default, this stuff should be logged to /var/log/auth.log

Answer (score 1):

I once had this problem. It was because root login was disallowed by the sshd configuration.

Ensure that `PermitRootLogin` is set to `yes` at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` config file, although I'm not exactly sure if this is where it's found under debian

Answer (score 1):

maybe that you got different keyboard mappings ?

try typing the password where you can see it.

Comment: good idea - but on inspection the passwords are the same...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for all the suggestions. I eventually solved by chance, by typing

```
$ passwd root
```

and doing everything the same as before. I have no idea why this worked when

```
$ whoami
root
$ passwd
```

didn't. Can anyone explain?